# "While asking" vs "Asking" vs "While I was asking"

Tags: sentence-choice

> A. **While asking** a previous question I was not sure whether to conclude by *asking* "A" or "B".
>
> B. **Asking** a previous question I was not sure whether to conclude by *asking* "A" or "B".
>
> C. **While I was asking** a previous question I was not sure whether to conclude by *asking* "A" or "B".

Are all of the above sentences grammatical? If so, how are they different in meaning and how can one avoid using "asking" two times?

Comment: As regards the repetition of "ask", you could always avoid that by starting with *"When I **posed** an earlier question..."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the above.

Most native speakers would say *"**When** asking a previous question I was not sure whether to..."*. But there's no difference in meaning, and none of these alternatives would be considered "odd".

---

We don't have the exact context, but personally I think I'd be more likely to say...

> *"**When I asked an earlier** question I wasn't sure whether to..."*